# MVVM Bindings not working properly

Tags: c#, mvvm

**Update**
*Managed to fix the selectedIndex problem. I'd forgotten to set SelectedItem as well and naturally that caused a few issues.*

So at 9AM this morning we got our 24 hour assignment and I have hit a brick wall.
We're supposed to create a program that allows a supervisor to Add and delete Employees and add Working Sessions, total hours and total earnings. But I am having some problems succesfully implementing this following the MVVM-Pattern. For some reason my Bindings simply aren't working and the only Solution I can see is someone looking over my project and helping me troubleshoot it.

Here is my code - I'm very sorry about having to post the entire thing but given that I have no clue where the problem is I did not see any other options. :

**EmployeeModel**

```
[Serializable]
public class WorkSessions : ObservableCollection<WorkSessionModel>
{
    public WorkSessions()
    {

    }
}
[Serializable]
public class WorkSessionModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime _dateTime;
    private string _id;
    private double _hours;

    public WorkSessionModel()
    {

    }

    public DateTime DateTime
    {
        get { return _dateTime; }
        set
        {
            _dateTime = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DateTime");
        }
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }
    public double Hours
    {
        get { return _hours; }
        set
        {
            _hours = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Hours");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalHours");
        }
    }


    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

**WorkSessionModel**

```
    [Serializable]
public class WorkSessions : ObservableCollection<WorkSessionModel>
{
    public WorkSessions()
    {

    }
}
[Serializable]
public class WorkSessionModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime _dateTime;
    private string _id;
    private double _hours;

    public WorkSessionModel()
    {

    }

    public DateTime DateTime
    {
        get { return _dateTime; }
        set
        {
            _dateTime = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DateTime");
        }
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }
    public double Hours
    {
        get { return _hours; }
        set
        {
            _hours = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Hours");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalHours");
        }
    }


    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

**EmployeeViewModel**

```
public class EmployeeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Employees _employeesModel = new Employees();
    public Employees EmployeesView = new Employees();

    public ObservableCollection<WorkSessionModel> WorkSessions { get; set; }

    private string _id = "0";
    private string _name = "noname";
    private double _wage = 0;
    private int _totalhours = 0;
    public string ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ID"); }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    public double Wage
    {
        get { return _wage; }
        set
        {
            _wage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Wage");
        }
    }
    public int TotalHours
    {
        get { return _totalhours; }
        set
        {
            _totalhours = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TotalHours");
        }
    }

    private EmployeeModel _selectedEmployee = new EmployeeModel();
    public EmployeeModel SelectedEmployee
    {
        get { return _selectedEmployee; }
        set
        {
            _selectedEmployee = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
        }
    }

    private int _selectedEmployeeIndex;
    public int SelectedEmployeeIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedEmployeeIndex; }
        set
        {
            _selectedEmployeeIndex = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedEmployeeIndex");
        }
    }

    #region RelayCommands

    // Employee Relay Commands
    public RelayCommand EmployeeAddNewCommand { set; get; }
    public RelayCommand EmployeeDeleteCommand { set; get; }
    public RelayCommand EmployeeNextCommand { set; get; }
    public RelayCommand EmployeePrevCommand { set; get; }
    public RelayCommand EmployeeTotalHoursCommand { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public EmployeeViewModel()
    {
        InitCommands();
    }

    private void InitCommands()
    {           
        EmployeeAddNewCommand = new RelayCommand(EmployeeAddNewExecute, EmployeeAddNewCanExecute);
        EmployeeDeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(EmployeeDeleteNewExecute, EmployeeDeleteCanExecute);
        EmployeeNextCommand = new RelayCommand(EmployeeNextExecute, EmployeeNextCanExecute);
        EmployeePrevCommand = new RelayCommand(EmployeePrevExecute, EmployeePrevCanExecute);
        //EmployeeTotalHoursCommand = new RelayCommand(EmployeeTotalHoursExecute, EmployeeTotalHoursCanExecute);
    }

    //private void EmployeeTotalHoursExecute()
    //{
    //    _selectedEmployee.TotalHours();
    //}

    //private bool EmployeeTotalHoursCanExecute()
    //{
    //    return true;
    //}

    private void EmployeeAddNewExecute()
    {
        EmployeeModel newEmployee = new EmployeeModel();
        EmployeesView.Add(newEmployee);
        _employeesModel.Add(newEmployee);
        SelectedEmployee = newEmployee;
    }

    private bool EmployeeAddNewCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void EmployeeDeleteNewExecute()
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("You are about delete all submissions for     Employee," + SelectedEmployee.Name + "(" + SelectedEmployee.ID +")\r\nAre you sure?", "This is a Warning!", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            _employeesModel.Remove(SelectedEmployee);
            EmployeesView.Remove(SelectedEmployee);
        }
    }

    private bool EmployeeDeleteCanExecute()
    {
        if (SelectedEmployee != null)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }

    private void EmployeeNextExecute()
    {
        SelectedEmployeeIndex++;
    }
    private bool EmployeeNextCanExecute()
    {
        if (SelectedEmployeeIndex < EmployeesView.Count - 1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    private void EmployeePrevExecute()
    {
        SelectedEmployeeIndex--;
    }
    private bool EmployeePrevCanExecute()
    {
        if (SelectedEmployeeIndex > 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public EmployeeViewModel EmployeeViewModel = new EmployeeViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        menu_employee.DataContext = EmployeeViewModel;
        sp_employees.DataContext = EmployeeViewModel;
        datagrid_employees.ItemsSource = EmployeeViewModel.EmployeesView;
        grid_selectedEmployee.DataContext =  EmployeeViewModel.SelectedEmployee;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well while a couple of things look a bit strange, i can't see a real problem here. What is "public Employees EmployeesView = new Employees();" for? Why is it public, when you have a model thats private. Also i would create a superclass for your property changed notification. Your WorkSessions property in the viewmodel, has a setter but no notification is raised when you reset it. remove the setter or add the notification. Besides that, i think we need some xaml code. But try not to post everything one example which is not working should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few problems with your code:

- When the SelectedIndex is updated, SelectedItem remains the same and vice versa.
- It looks like your data binding is out of order:

The `DataContext` property cascades down to every child of a certain dependency object.

The code in the MainWindow constructor should probably be replaced by:

```
this.DataContext = EmployeeViewModel;
```

Then in XAML set the rest of the properties using Data Binding. The problem in your situation is that the DataContext of the selectedemployee is only set once. This means if you select another employee, then it will not update.

An example for your SelectedEmployee grid:

```
<Grid Name="grid_selectedEmployee" DataContext="{Binding SelectedEmployee, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">...</Grid>
```

Comment: So thanks to you I finally managed to get my bindings to work..somewhat. It seems that my SelectedIndex isn't getting updated properly. I can traverse the items in the DataGrid just fine using the "<<" and ">>" buttons. However when I try to edit the data, Only the values of the last item is being set. http://imgur.com/VjP26

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest things I see is you are **setting** properties, not **binding** them.

For example,

```
datagrid_employees.ItemsSource = EmployeeViewModel.EmployeesView;
```

You are telling your DataGrid that it's ItemsSource should **be** that specific object. You need to bind it to that value so you are telling it to **point to** that property instead. This will make your UI correctly reflect what's in your ViewModel

The other huge red flag I see is your ViewModel referencing something called and `EmployeeView` which leads me to believe your View and ViewModel too closely tied together.
Your `ViewModel` should contain all your business logic and code, while the View is usually XAML and simply reflects the ViewModel in a user-friendly way.

The View and the ViewModel should never directly reference each other (I have had my View reference my ViewModel in some rare occasions, but never the other way around)

For example, an `EmployeesViewModel` might contain

- `ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees`
- `Employee SelectedEmployee`
- `ICommand AddEmployeeCommand`
- `ICommand DeleteEmployeeCommand`

while your View (XAML) might look like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddEmployeeCommand}" />
        <Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteEmployeeCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}">
        ... etc
    </DataGrid>

    <UniformGrid DataContext="{Binding SelectedEmployee}" Columns="2" Rows="4">
        <TextBlock Text="ID" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Id}" />
        ... etc
    </UniformGrid >
</StackPanel>
```

And the only thing you should be setting is the DataContext of the entire Window. Usually I overwrite `App.OnStartup()` to start up my application:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var view = new MainWindow();
        var vm = new EmployeesViewModel;
        view.DataContext = vm;
        view.Show();
    }
}
```

Although I suppose in your case this would also work:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext =  new EmployeesViewModel();
}
```